# A metric on a power set of a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $A,B$ are nonempety subsets of a metrix space $(X,d)$. Define

$$D(A,B) = \inf_{a\in A, \; b \in B } d(a,b) $$

Is this a metrix on $P(X)$? The power set of $X$. My claim is that it is indeed not, but i cannot find a counter example that violates the triangle inequality. Obviously, the other properties a metric must satisfy are obvious in this case. However, i cannot find one that will fail the triangle inequality.

thanks

Comment: Actually, one of the other conditions fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** While not violating the triangle inequality, here's a reason why this is not a metric. Let $A\cap B\neq\varnothing$, but $A\neq B$. Calculate $D(A,B)$.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I suspect $D(A,B)=0$, but I am unable to prove it. Can you help me? thank you very much.

Comment: Learner, let $x\in A\cap B$. In the calculation of $D(A,B)$ set $a=b=x$. What happens then?

Comment: IT is 0. But my question is: why do we need to pick $a=b=x$? Is it because the distance $D$ holds for every $a \in A$ and $b \in B$? But in this case, the case when they are equal, then we have $d(x,x) = 0$ ?

Comment: Yes. That's why. Note that as Michael points out, we can have that with $A\cap B=\varnothing$ by taking sets which are "very very close". But this example is easier to understand, I think.

Comment: this means that the converse of your statement does not hold. correct?

Comment: If by converse you mean that if they are disjoint then $D(A,B)\neq 0$, then it doesn't hold, as Michael points out.

Comment: I mean, $D(A,B) = 0$, then $A \cap B \neq \varnothing $

Comment: Yeah, so as Michael points out, that's not true.

Comment: but i can tell intuitively that $D( [0,1), [1,2]) = 0$, but how can we prove this rigorously ?

Comment: By picking a sequence of pairs, whose distances approach zero.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the list reasons  of why it is not a metric, note that $D\big([0,1),[1,2]\big)=0$, when we endow $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric.

Comment: I can see your example intiuitively, but can you explain the proof why is it $0$? thanks

Comment: @Learner For each $\epsilon>0$, you can find points in these sets with distance less than $\epsilon$. For example, $1$ and $1-\epsilon/2$. So the infimum over all distancs can not be strictly positive. On the other hand, it cannot be negative either. So it must be $0$. Btw: A point $x$ in a metric space is in the closure of a set $C$ if and only if $D(\{x\},C)$ using your definition.

Answer (score 2):

You gave me an excuse to learn image-editing with GIMP

[image: My_Image]